# Javascript Variable Clarification

Tags: javascript

I came across this behavior while trying to write some tests for my code and was wondering if somebody could explain to me why this isn't performing as I expect it to.

I have the following code:

```
var arr = [];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log('pushing %s', i);
    arr.push(function() {
        console.log('logging %s - random %s', i, Math.random());
    });
}

for (ai in arr) {
    arr[ai]();
}
```

which outputs out something like this:

```
pushing 0
pushing 1
pushing 2
pushing 3
pushing 4
logging 5 - random 0.35618519759736955
logging 5 - random 0.4480402651242912
logging 5 - random 0.9252766149584204
logging 5 - random 0.4456857305485755
logging 5 - random 0.14507507369853556
```

though I was expecting it to output something like this:

```
pushing 0
pushing 1
pushing 2
pushing 3
pushing 4
logging 0 - random 0.35618519759736955
logging 1 - random 0.4480402651242912
logging 2 - random 0.9252766149584204
logging 3 - random 0.4456857305485755
logging 4 - random 0.14507507369853556
```

How is `i` changing after I've already pushed to the array? and why does `i` resolve to `5` in the `logging ...` lines even though it only reaches `4` in the `pushing ...` lines?

Comment: Because your `i` variable is global. And even if it was declared with `var`, it would be free in those pushed functions.

Comment: infamous loop .......

Comment: @Bergi: sorry for the duplicate, I didn't even know how to describe what my problem was, thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: No problem, glad I could help with only a link :-)